# PHP foreach not behaving as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (POSTed from a Python application) called "observations". It looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        ['remote_id'] => 1
        ['dimension_id'] => 1
        ['metric'] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        ['remote_id'] => 1
        ['dimension'] => 2
        ['metric'] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        ['remote_id'] => 1
        ['dimension_id'] => 3
        ['metric'] => 3
    )
 (etc)
```

I want to iterate through all those instances of remote_id, dimension_id and metric and write them to a database. But I can't access them - here's my PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST["observations"] as $observation) {
echo "Let's try and access the whole array... \n";
print_r ($observation);
echo "But what about the sub elements? \n";
print_r ($observation[0]);
print_r ($observation['dimension_id']);
}
```

This returns:

```
Let's try and access the whole array... 
Array
(
    ['remote_id'] => 1
    ['dimension_id'] => 1
    ['metric'] => 1
)
But what about the sub elements? 
Let's try and access the whole array... 
Array
(
    ['remote_id'] => 1
    ['dimension'] => 2
    ['metric'] => 2
)
But what about the sub elements? 
(etc)
```

So my print_r ($observation[0]) and print_r ($observation['dimension_id']) are both failing to access the appropriate sub-elements and returning empty. What am I missing here?

Edit: a few questions about my (potentially malformed) POST. Doing it in Python like so:

```
data = urllib.urlencode([
       ("observations[0]['remote_id']", 1),
       ("observations[0]['dimension_id']", 1),
       ("observations[0]['metric']",metric1),

       ("observations[1]['remote_id']", 1),
       ("observations[1]['dimension']", 2),
       ("observations[1]['metric']", metric2),

       ("observations[2]['remote_id']", 1),
       ("observations[2]['dimension_id']", 3),
       ("observations[2]['metric']",metric3),

       ("observations[3]['remote_id']", 1),
       ("observations[3]['dimension_id']", 4),
       ("observations[3]['metric']",metric4),

       ("observations[4]['remote_id']", 1),
       ("observations[4]['dimension_id']", 5),
       ("observations[4]['metric']",metric5),
    ])
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url=url, data=data)
```

Comment: There's no index 0 in `$observation`. Index `dimension_id` exists and also `dimension` - which is right?

Comment: `$observation['dimension_id']` should work. Enable error reporting and you will get noticed for the wrong keys

Comment: Look at `var_dump(array_keys($observation))`, then look at [this](http://3v4l.org/D3eRR). Seems like your POSTed keys have extra quotes and you need to use `$observation["'metric'"]` instead of the usual `$observation['metric']`. (Of course, the right solution would be to fix your POSTing code *not* to add those extra quotes in the first place.)

Comment: Odd - I've updated the original with my POST generator.

Comment: You don't need those single quotes in the POST field names. Look at the [field-naming examples in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works according to your given array:

```
$array = Array(
        0 => Array
        (
            'remote_id' => 1,
            'dimension_id' => 1,
            'metric' => 1
        ),
        1 => Array
            (
                'remote_id' => 1,
                'dimension_id' => 2,
                'metric' => 2
            ),
        2 => Array
            (
                'remote_id' => 1,
                'dimension_id' => 3,
                'metric' => 3
            )
);  
foreach ($array as $observation) {

    echo "Remote id: ". $observation['remote_id']."<br />";
    echo "Dimension id: ". $observation['remote_id']."<br />";
    echo "Metric: ". $observation['metric']."<br />";
}
```

That will print:

```
Remote id: 1
Dimension id: 1
Metric: 1
Remote id: 1
Dimension id: 1
Metric: 2
Remote id: 1
Dimension id: 1
Metric: 3
```

But it looks like your `$_POST["observations"]` is not an array of `$observation`'s but just one `$observation`.

There is probably something wrong in your form. Did you use arrays in your input like 
`<input type="text" name="observations[0]['metric']" />`?

Comment: Odd - updating original with my POST definition in Python.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have knowledge of python.